# QPython Android PySpeedTest

Tags: python-3.x, sl4a, qpython, qpython3, speed-test

I installed this module PySpeedTest on the QPython on Android`enter code here` and tried running the below code

```
import pyspeedtest
st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()
ping = st.ping()
download = st.download()
upload = st.upload()

print('ping: ' + str(ping))
print('download: ' + str(download))
print('upload: ' + str(upload))

which returns

ping: 20.457208156585693
download: 79367128.02705236
upload: 8458681.882858781
```

The above code dosent seem to work . I got from this link

https://pypi.org/project/pyspeedtest/

can somebody please help me.

Comment: What did you get? Post your traceback so someone can help you.

Comment: Did you get `Exception: Cannot find a test server`? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999879/pyspeedtest-cannot-find-test-server) if you did.