# pyspeedtest cannot find test server

Tags: python

I'm trying to use pyspeedtest to get the upload/download speed of my connecting but I keep getting the following error which I couldn't resolve:

```
import pyspeedtest
st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()
st.download()

Exception: Cannot find a test server
```

Any suggestions/insights would be welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually does work if you change the url in the pyspeedtest.py file from www.speedtest.net to c.speedtest.net on line 186 in v1.2.7 of the script.

*Edit: added an example of how to get it to work*

You can edit the pyspeedtest.py script (located at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspeedtest.py on my raspberry pi 3) by using vi, e.g.:

```
sudo vi /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspeedtest.py
```

Go to line 186 and change the following line:

```
connection = self.connect('www.speedtest.net')
```

to:

```
connection = self.connect('c.speedtest.net')
```

Then run pyspeedtest using the wrapper in /usr/local/bin:

```
/usr/local/bin/pyspeedtest
Using server: speedtest.wilkes.net
Ping: 41 ms
Download speed: 46.06 Mbps
Upload speed: 11.58 Mbps
```

Or use the python interpreter:

```
>>> import pyspeedtest
>>> st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()
>>> st.ping()
41.70024394989014
>>> st.download()
44821310.72337018
>>> st.upload()
14433296.732646577
```

Comment: This should probably just be a comment

Comment: Can you improve the answer by adding an example?

Comment: SpeedTest Object takes a host parameter, there is no need to change pyspeedtest package at all. st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest(host="c.speedtest.net")

Answer (score 5):

The project hasn't been updated since mid-2016. And the last update was [updated user-agent to prevent SpeedTest block...](https://github.com/fopina/pyspeedtest/commit/d6841707152ed7d44da689555333c451e0512a91) And if you skim the code, there are [comments like this]:(https://github.com/fopina/pyspeedtest/blob/master/pyspeedtest.py#L188)

```
    # really contribute to speedtest.net OS statistics
    # maybe they won't block us again...
```

And there have been [bugs posted to GitHub](https://github.com/fopina/pyspeedtest/issues) about the project not working, with no response.

So, my guess is: This project probably violates SpeedTest.net's terms of service, so they blocked it. The author tried to get around the block, they blocked it again, and the author gave up. In the intervening two years, any other servers it used as backups either blocked it, or shut down (e.g., speedtest.serv.pt, mentioned in the docs, no longer exists).

There is [a pull request from another user](https://github.com/fopina/pyspeedtest/pull/16) that might fix it, although it appears to be failing the CI test. If you want to try it yourself, you can.

But otherwise, you can't use this library, and there's no way anyone can help you use it; it just doesn't work. You'll have to find another way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to do my own tests with my own server:

To generate the network test file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test-network
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /test_network {
        root /home/www/example.com;
           # serve file
    }

    # redirect the rest to HTTPS conf block
    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Then restart nginx.

Now I get output with `wget` like:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/test_network
... 3,63MB/s ...
```